# How do I keep saran wrap (plastic wrap, cling wrap) from clinging to itself?

Tags: food, kitchen

To tenderize meat, I first place it between two sheets of saran wrap, and then beat it with a meat tenderizer mallet. It's not wrapped tightly, else the wrap would just break when you hammered it. Placing the two sheets is always a nuisance, and the saran wrap inevitably ends up folding over itself, requiring me to fuss with it more than I'd like.

Is there a better way to spread saran wrap onto my countertop such that it doesn't fold and cling to itself?

Comment: It's the point of clingfilm, that it clings to itself. If it didn't it would be no good for its day job of wrapping things airtight. Use a freezer bag.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to not cut the wrap until you have wrapped the meat.

Hold the meat in one hand and pull the wrap towards you with the other.  Now place the wrap on the meat and rotate the meat towards you such that you're wrapping it.

I don't know how much you wrap it.  I would imagine quite a lot, as you're hitting it with a hammer.  In any case, wrap it until your satisfied, and then use the cutting device.

Comment: I actually place the saran wrap in the center of a square piece of wrap–if you wrapped it tightly, the wrap would just break when you hammered it. This won't work for me–I'll reword my question to clarify.

Comment: I would imagine you can control the amount of tightness.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to use one piece of cling wrap. Stretch it out on your counter top, place the meat onto it, and then fold the cling wrap back and cut it.

If your issue is separating the cling wrap after you've hammered the meat, you could place a piece of paper near the end of the cling wrap so that this part of the cling wrap doesn't cling onto the underlying cling wrap.